# Properly align boxes two by two

Tags: html, css

I have boxes that are in rows three by three, on a wider screen (PC). I want to make them align two per row on smaller screens (Mobile phone), to take up full width of the screen (including margin, padding...). How could i achieve this? Also some of them are 40px higher than others. Right now i have this CSS for wider screens:

```
.parents-parent {
    margin: auto;
    width: 700px;
}
.parent {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid rgb(230,230,230);
    margin: 10px;
  }
  .parent:nth-child(3n + 1) {
   clear: left; 
 }
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="parents-parent">
{% for exam in exams %}

  <div class="parent" exam-id="{{ exam.pk }}" csrf="{{ csrf_token }}">

    <div class="exam-title">
      <a><b>Test številka {{ exam.exam_number }}</b></a>
    </div>

  <a class="exam-span-wrapper">
    <div class="exam-box-el  exam-span-file">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> Test
    </div>

    <ul class="exam-ul">
      {% for file in exam.examfile_set.all %}
      <li class="exam-li-img" src="{{ file.exam_file.url }}" alt="Slika Testa" width="60" height="60" class="img-resposive exam-img">Slika Testa {{ forloop.counter }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>

  </a>

  <a class="comment">
    <div class="exam-box-el"> 
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Komentarji
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="mark-exam">
    <div class="exam-box-el">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle {% if user in exam.exam_mark.all %}active{% endif %}"></span> Potrebno popravka
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="{% url 'profile' exam.exam_user %}">
    <div class="exam-box-el">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {{ exam.exam_user }}
    </div>
  </a> 

  {% if exam.exam_user == user %}
  <a href="#" class="remove-exam">
    <div class="exam-box-el more">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove glyphicon-remove-exam"></span>
        Odstrani
    </div>
  </a>
  {% endif %}

</div>


{% endfor %}

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `@media` query where your layout will currently start to break, and specify a width that will occupy 50% of the row, and clear every `:nth-child(odd)` element instead.

```css
.parent {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
  margin: 10px;
}

.parent:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  clear: left;
}

@media (max-width: 682px) {
  .parent:nth-child(3n + 1) {
    clear: none;
  }
  .parent:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .parent {
    width: calc(50% - 22px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">foo</div>
<div class="parent">foo</div>
<div class="parent">foo</div>
<div class="parent">foo</div>
<div class="parent">foo</div>
<div class="parent">foo</div>
<div class="parent">foo</div>
<div class="parent">foo</div>
<div class="parent">foo</div>
```

Comment: this works great! Is there any way to center .parents-parent as margin: auto doesnt seem to work? Also i didnt include parent calc width, as it stretches box

Comment: @skin great. A specified `width` and `margin: auto` will center a block element horizontally. If that isn't working, you need to include the relevant code that reproduces the problem. What you have now will center .parents-parent. But please avoid changing your question or asking new questions after making the original post - that sounds like a new problem, so if you need help, make a new post.